# Change a property name at runtime

Tags: c#, reflection, field

Can I change the field of a class at runtime in c#?

for example, if i have the class:

```
public class ExampleClass{
    public string Name;
}
```

can I Change it at runtime, using reflection or other techniques, to change the Name to Name1?

```
public class ExampleClass{
    public string Name1;
}
```

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: I need to create a class without knowing the names of the properties beforehando to pass this class to a funtion that creates a grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot change the actual members of a type at runtime

Options:

- create a new type on the fly, that looks a lot like `ExampleClass`, but has different members - and presumably some mapping code between them
- if the intent is for some kind of runtime binding, consider `ICustomTypeDescriptor` or `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` - which will allow some frameworks to treat it *as though* it had a `Name1`, even though it actually doesn't (note: things like `DynamicObject` and `ExpandoObject` include implementations of `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`, but you can do it in other ways)
- use an indexer, i.e. so that `var val = obj["Name1"];` returns something meaningful

Comment: Can you please give me a link to an example, or an example of how to create a new type on the fly, without knowing beforehand the name of the fields? or that i have the name of the fields in a list of strings? thanks.

Comment: @Albert that is a very advanced topic. TypeBuilder is where to start

Comment: @Marc agreed!   TypeBuilder and Reflection.Emit would be a place for this!  You can also look at Lambda Expression Trees.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at DynamicObject:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx