# C# dynamically change property type

Tags: c#, class, types, properties, type-conversion

I'm trying to dynamically changing a property type in my code, for example, at *Person* class bellow how can I change property *name* type from bool to string?

```
public class Person
{     
    public bool name;    
}
```

Comment: Do you mean at runtime?

Comment: Cannot be done.  Cannot think of why anyone would want to do that.

Comment: You can create a typegeneric type, so you can create a Person with bool name and another Person with string name. Anyway, probably you are thinking to complex leading to this idea.

Comment: This might be an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What initial problem gave rise to this attempted solution?

Comment: Ok, I'm searching for different solutions, but I had this doubt so I decided to post here, thanks for your answers. Anyway, I'm working with Entity framework, ASP.NET MVC in azure, my application uses _n_ databases, so I have to constantly change context in order to synchronize my data, 2 databases use same context definition (exactly same tables), but now one table in just one of these databases had a different property, so I was trying to change just one property type from my context without having to create another class or a generic type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do that at runtime you have different options. Some of them:

1) Make the property object and check types wherever you use it:

```
public class Person
{     
    public object Name;    
}
```

2) Create a generic type for Person that allows you to define different instances of the class for different types:

```
public class Person<T>
{     
    public T Name;    
}

var boolPerson = new Person<bool>();
boolPerson.Name = true;
var stringPerson = new Person<string>();
stringPerson.Name = "aString";
```

However you should explain why do you want to do this as there could be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109397/change-a-property-name-at-runtime) (you can create a dynamic object and change that object at runtime).

Comment: stackoverflow best practice is to provide the example here as links may not age well and may even quit working.